# Javascript: Editing object property changes property from different object

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I want to set object a equal to object b and then edit property x from object a.
But, when I edit a.x, b.x gets changed too for some reason. How do I work around this?

```
var b = {
    x: 0,
    y: 3

};
var a = b;
alert(b.x); //outputs 0
a.x = 1;
alert(b.x); //outputs 1?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `b` is pointing to the same object `a`, i.e, both variables are referencing the same object created initially. Instead, copy all properties to a new object using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method.

```js
var b = {
  x: 0,
  y: 3

};
var a = Object.assign({}, b);
alert(b.x); //outputs 0
a.x = 1;
alert(b.x); //outputs 1?
```

---

For older browser check [polyfill option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) of the method.

---

Refer :[Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)